# Why do we need to git push first before git pull?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

I have both local changes and remote changes.

Someone told me I must do push first, then pull. Any reason behind this?

Comment: This person is wrong. Your changes will not be accepted by the remote. You need to *pull* before pushing, not the other way around.

Answer (score 41):

That person is wrong: the right model is `pull-before-you-push` and not the reverse.

When you `pull`, `git` will fetch commits on `origin` and will try to `fast-forward` your local commits on top of them, doing the merge. After that you can `push` in this way you will not generate conflicts with other updates.